# What's the reason for silver spoon at yichud door?

Tags: minhag, marriage, wedding, chabad, yichud-seclusion

At a wedding, according to [Chabad custom](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/477338/jewish/Yichud-Room.htm), a silver spoon is placed at the entrance to the yichud room. The chosson walks in first by stepping over it with his right foot first. What is the significance of this?

Comment: See Rabbi Zalmanov's comment at the end of that article.

Comment: Perhaps it's related to the (non-Jewish) practice of the groom presenting the bride with an engraved silver teaspoon on their wedding day to symbolize that they will never go hungry and/or the practice of the new couple stepping over a broom into their new marriage (see, e.g.,: http://traditionscustoms.com/wedding-traditions/strange-wedding-traditions )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Some](http://www.chabadtalk.com/forum/showpost.php3?p=25182&postcount=3) say the reason is for **parnoso**  and lihavdil as @Loewian says above.

Some people say [by foot note 14](http://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9F#cite_note-14)

> מנהג לשים כף כסף בפתח חדר הייחוד של חתן וכלה, ואמר לי כך:
>   אחד הדרכים שהאישה מתקדשת בהם הוא קידושי כסף, ובדרך זו נוהגים למעשה לקדש את האישה. אמנם לפועל הקידושין נעשים בהרבה קהילות על ידי טבעת זהב שהיא שווה כסף אך איננה כסף ממש. ומאחר וכסף מסמל על אהבה מלשון "נכסוף נכספתי", לכן כדי להשלים את העניין מבחינה רוחנית, ולהשלים את ה"קידושין בכסף", מניחים כף כסף בפתח חדר הייחוד שלכמה דעות הוא השלמת הקידושין. כף מסמלת כלי קיבול, ובעניין זה כלי קיבול לאהבה.  ‏
>   (Source).
>   [14] הרב ברוך בליזינסקי, כפר חב"ד.‏

or [footnote 13](http://m.abc770.org//article/node/1958#_ftn13)

> [13] על פי "ספר המנהגים חב"ד" עמ' 76. אפשר שהטעם להנחת כף הכסף הוא כי כסף מורה על חסד ואהבה וכף מורה על כלי קבול ועל כן מניחים זאת בתחילת התייחדותם של החתן והכלה בחדר ייחוד.‏

Or as @Yishai sais in comment above
["See Rabbi Zalmanov's comment at the end of that article."](http://m.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/477338/jewish/Yichud-Room.htm)

> August 27, 2015.
>   Re: why the silver spoon.
>   The wedding ring used to be made of silver, "kesef" in Hebrew. It is similar to the Hebrew word "kosef," which means yearning and love. Because most people use gold rings today, the silver spoon represents this same affection.  
>   All things in Judaism start with the right hand or foot, because it represents strength and permanence.
>   Eliezer Zalmanov
>   for Chabad.org

The reason is that silver is connected to **love** (as the Rebbe says [in sif 15.3)](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/tm/10/24/199.htm)

> ג) קידושין הו"ע של אהבה, שזהו"ע כסף, מלשון "נכסוף נכספת")

and the spoon is a receptacle.

---

It is brought in [Sefer HaMinhagim](http://www.sichos-in-english.org/books/sefer-haminhagim/65.htm)

> After the chuppah a silver spoon is placed on the threshold of the yichud room. The chassan steps over it as he enters, followed by the kallah.

---

The Rebbe in a shicha said that the minhagim of the nosi hador are for everyone to do especially the minhagai hasuno that is giluy... [Page 198 sif י](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/tm/10/24/198.htm)

> י. האמור לעיל הוא בנוגע למנהגים בכלל. ובפרט בנוגע למנהגי חתונה – ה"ז בודאי נוגע לכל, שהרי בנישואין צריך להתגלות כח האין-סוף ב"דור ישרים יבורך", וכיון שהתגלות כח הא"ס נמשכת ע"י נשיא הדור, לכן נוגע יותר **שתהי'** ההנהגה במנהגי בית הרב.‏

And one of these minhagim was to step over a silver spoon  [page 200](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/tm/10/24/200?search=%d7%9b%d7%a3+%d7%a9%d7%9c+%d7%9b%d7%a1%d7%a3)

> היתה מונחת על סף דלת חדר היחוד כף של כסף, והציווי הי' שלא לדרוך עלי', אלא רק לעבור על גבה.

**Edit** 
Another reason for silver by a wedding is that silver is a good siman in Hebrew (כסף) the numerical number increases with each letter (20, 60, 80) 
From Chukai Noshim Ben Ish Chai chapter 45

[image]

Comment: I don't think the question was asking for the source, rather the reason/significance.

Comment: @Yishai I am looking for it, it is for parnoso

Comment: Re "The Rebbe in a [sicha] said that the minhagim of the nosi hador are for everyone to do": See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6146: "There are practices that are known to have been specific to the Rebbeim"... "in the absence of any evidence that this was meant as a template for others to follow, we might well assume that this was one of the Rebbe's private minhagim"

Comment: @msh210 I see no source there but I brought a source, it is possible I am wrong but I need a source more than an answer on mi yodeya

Comment: @hazoriz re your comment: First of all, your source refers to customs at a wedding only, not in general, AFAICT, whereas your answer makes it sound like it refers to customs in general. Second, that _sicha_ in  תורת מנחם is בלתי מוגה. Third, Rabbi Alex Heppenheimer who wrote that answer *is* a source (though I have no way of evaluating his reliability versus that of the publishers of תורת מנחם). Fourth, _en, hachi nami_, maybe you're right, and maybe R'AH would even agree to it (inasmuch as he wasn't writing about a wedding specifically); I'm just pointing out what he said.

Comment: @msh210 1. Please reread the source and the previous paragraph on the previous page 197 sif ט,( to me it seems you are wrong about the first point), 2. You are correct about the second point, 3. I see only "Alex" even is it is the one who you say it is (I am sorry but) I do not know his credentials, 4. See reply to point 1

Comment: @msh210 I will ask Alex by his answer to explain (back up) his opinion

Comment: @msh210 And sif ח "לאחרי שרבותינו נשיאינו גילו ענינים אלו, צריך כאו"א לעשותם בעצמו."

Comment: He's not been active on-site of late; I doubt he'll reply to comments on his answer. I hope he does, though. And thanks for pointing out the preceding _s'ipim_ to me.